# ASP.net C# : Managing connections in public class

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am beginner in ASP.net. Trying to develop a class to manage  my sql connections. I have saved my connection string in my webconfig. 
The only problem I face is with this class all my connections remain open.
How can I close a connection using constructors in my class?

```
 public class DBSettings
{
    static string DBConn

    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString; }
    }


    public static SqlConnection sqlConn
    {
        get
        {
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(DBConn);
            Conn.Open();
            return Conn;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: why would you approach this like above?!

Comment: This approach increases the readability and in case you wanna change the connection string, you only need to do it once.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. You need to learn about [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), which SqlConnection implements.

Comment: I concur, this is a bad idea.  SQL connections are pooled for you automatically.  There is zero reason to do this.

Comment: In your current implementation you will need to explicitly close the connection and dispose of resources, such as SqlDataReader. I must concur with Mason and Amy utilizing IDisposible or utilizing the using statement which essentially implements a try finally block. This allows the system to manage and free those resources. Stated differently, it prevents forgotten resource management and cleanup.